# When I use strftime in awk, it adds one hour. How to fix

Tags: awk

When I try to convert seconds to show `H:M:S`, `strftime` in `awk` adds one hour.
Why and how to fix?
Eks

```
echo "3600" | awk '{print strftime("%T",$1)}'
02:00:00  # Here i would like to see 01:00:00

echo "60" | awk '{print strftime("%T",$1)}'
01:01:00  # Here i would like to see 00:01:00
```

This gives correct result, but is this normal to do?

```
echo "72" | awk '{print strftime("%T",int($1)-3600)}'
00:01:12
```

---

Edit: Here is a workaround, but I still like to now why strftime does not give me correct answer.

```
echo "3958" | awk '{h=int($0/3600);m=int(($0-h*3600)/60);s=($0-h*3600-m*60);printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s}'
01:05:58

echo "64" | awk '{h=int($0/3600);m=int(($0-h*3600)/60);s=($0-h*3600-m*60);printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",h,m,s}'
00:01:04
```

Comment: It depend on your timezone.

Comment: So to calculate `12:44:12 - 12:44:08 = 4 seconds` and I would like to display it back to `0:0:4`, I need to subtract my timezone if I use `strftime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GNU awk you can add the utc-flag to use Universal Time Code.

From the man-page:

```
strftime([format [, timestamp[, utc-flag]]])
  Formats  timestamp  according  to  the  specification  in format.  If utc-flag is present and is non-zero or non-null, the result is in UTC, otherwise the
  result is in local time.  The timestamp should be of the same form as returned by systime().  If timestamp is missing, the current time of  day  is  used.
  If  format  is missing, a default format equivalent to the output of date(1) is used.  See the specification for the strftime() function in ANSI C for the
  format conversions that are guaranteed to be available.
```

Example:

```
echo "3600" | awk '{print strftime("%T",$1,1)}'
01:00:00
```